# Vue.js don't work with external JSON in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, vue.js

I want to get data from external JSON file for one var. I think the problem is what I using in-html vue.js and Vue.js don't understand what I wrote for him:joy:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8xenxfj/)
And the second problem is what I can't use value from json:

```js
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                searchResult: [],
                search: '',
            }
        },

        created: function() {
            this.searchResult = [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "title": "d",
                    "img": "src"
                }
            ];
        },

        computed: {
            filteredName: function() {
                return this.searchResult.filter((x) => {
                    return x.title.match(this.search)
                });
            },
            allOK: function () {
                if (this.search.valueOf() === "") {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true
                }
            },
            hrefResult: function () {
                return "/item?=" + this.searchResult.id
            }
        }
    });
```

What I'm gonna do? :(

Comment: And I'm using Vue.js in HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using [*ECMAScript Imports*](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) outside of a `module` script. The `import` keyword is only recognized inside `<script type="module">`, so your usage would result in a syntax error: `Unexpected identifier` on the line of your `import` statement (where you try to import `json/products.json`).

There are a couple solutions that require a modern browser (and polyfills for older browsers).

*OPTION 1:* Change your `script` to include `type="module"`, and make sure to use relative paths in the import path. [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hr3AV3sxP0xGswzb700R?p=preview)

```
<!-- inside HTML file -->
<script type="module">
  import products from './json/products.json.js'

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        items: products
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

*OPTION 2:* Fetch the external JSON file instead of importing it. [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RPS8I3nMS6SFpP90CpLI?p=preview)

```
<!-- inside HTML file -->
<script>
  (async () => {
    const productsResponse = await fetch('./json/products.json');
    const products = await productsResponse.json();

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data () {
        return {
          items: products
        }
      }
    })
  })();
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could switch to [`vue-cli`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) projects, which includes transpiling in its build, allowing you to use `imports` for external JSON files. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/v3ll1ww49l)